# why Android recorded video could not play in open source js- HTML5 video player?

Tags: video

i have tried out html5 video element to play android phone recorded video in web browser but not played then used opensource html5 video player it plays all video except android phone recorded video. how can i figure it out please tell me ASAP. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Given your description of the problem, my best guess is that the phone recorded the video in a format that is not playable through most HTML5 video implementations. Most such implementations are able to play H.264 video encoding in an MP4 file. It's possible that your Android phone encoded the video using MPEG-4 part 2 video, while also storing it in an MP4 container. This codec is not supported by any HTML5 video implementations I know of.

Also, what web browser(s) did you try? I haven't kept up on whether current Firefox supports H.264 yet. So it could be that you have an H.264 video, but the specific browser can't play it.

In order to analyze the video deeper, download it to a computer and run it through [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/), dig through the menus, and find the codec information.

Comment: Ok thanks, now can you help me for ..
how to play .mp4 video recorded by android mobile in all web browser please any idea..

Comment: Configure Android to record in H.264 and not MPEG-4 part 2 video (both will come packaged in a .mp4 container), assuming my stated assumptions are correct.